# foxpro program freezes while it is running

Tags: windows, foxpro

I am using foxpro apps under Windows 7. During the compilation one of my program it suddenly became freezing until I move the mouse or press any key. And this happens all the time while I am working with prog.

This happens when I move only the data to a mapped directory on the host. If my application, foxpro and the data are in the same directory on the virtual machine there are no problem with it. 
This happens when my data is not on the virtual machine.

Can it be a caching issue?

Comment: I wonder if this issue is a broken connection to the drive and VFP searching for it. I've seen cases where VFP is very slow in certain operations when there's a non-existent folder in the path. Wondering if this is something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WOW]
```

Save export as backup. Then change value "DefaultSeparateVDM" to "yes"

If you have 64bit then you need to create a file for 16bit applications that use the internal start command in separate memory space as follows:

Start /separate command

Also have a look at this article. http://www.reddit.com/r/Database/comments/2kz0x5/dbf_file_getting_corrupt/

There kind of similar problem, who knows, maybe it would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar in the past, and it doesn't have to do with VFP application and data residing in the same folder.  What has happened to me is the  debugger.  You mention "...while I am working with the prog." tells me you are in the VFP development mode, and not run-time from the app itself.  If you have issues where your debugger has breakpoints, or other flags that have become corrupted somehow, I have done

CLEAR DEBUGGER

But that is something going back several years and MIGHT be what you are encountering.